# Adding and removing checkbox values to an array from many groups of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the below code. How can I add and remove value from checkbox groups into an array?

Apparently I am able to add the values on checking the checkbox but my attempts to remove same value on un-checking the checkbox didn't work!

```js
 
 let opts = [];
 $('input:checkbox[name=a]').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
       let val = $(this).data('shape');
        opts.push(val);
        console.log(opts);
       }
       else{
                let val = $(this).data('shape');
       opts.filter(a => a !== val);
       console.log(opts);
       }
  
});

 $('input:checkbox[name=b]').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
       let val = $(this).data('shape');
        opts.push(val);
        console.log(opts);
       }
       else{
         let val = $(this).data('shape');
       opts.filter(a => a !== val);
       console.log(opts);
       }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb2"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb3"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb4" />


<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb2"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb3"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb4"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `opts.filter(a => a !== val);` to work you have to assign the new value again like: `opts = opts.filter(a => a !== val);`

You can also use `opts.splice( $.inArray(val, opts), 1 )`; It will remove the selected `val` from your array

Note: you can improve your function by allowing multiple select, `$('input:checkbox[name=a],input:checkbox[name=b]')`

**Demo**

```js
let opts = [];
$('input:checkbox[name=a],input:checkbox[name=b]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    let val = $(this).data('shape');
    opts.push(val);
    console.log(opts);
  } else {
    let val = $(this).data('shape');
    opts.splice( $.inArray(val, opts), 1 )
    console.log(opts);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb4" />


<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb4" />
```

Here is a updated version of your code:

```
$('input:checkbox[name=a],input:checkbox[name=b]').on('change', function() {
  let val = $(this).data('shape');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    opts.push(val);
  } else {
    opts.splice( $.inArray(val, opts), 1 )
  }
  console.log(opts);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let opts = [];
 $('input:checkbox[name=a],[name=b]').change(function(){

  let val = $(this).data('shape');
  
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
  {      
        opts.push(val);
        console.log(opts);
       }
       else
       {         
         opts.splice( $.inArray($(this).data('shape'), opts), 1 );
         console.log(opts);
       }  
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb1" > First </input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb2"  > Second </input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb3"  > Three</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb4" > Four</input><br>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb1"  >Five</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb2"  >Six</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb3"  >Seven</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb4"  >Eight</input><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` to remove unchecked data,hope this helps

```js
let opts = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  let val = $(this).data('shape');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    opts.push(val);
    console.log(opts);
  } else {
    opts = opts.filter(function(elem) {
      return elem != val;
    });
    console.log(opts);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let opts = [];
$('input:checkbox[name=a]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    let val = $(this).data('shape');
    opts.push(val);
    console.log(opts);
  } else {
    let val = $(this).data('shape');
    opts = opts.filter(a => a !== val);
    console.log(opts);
  }

});

$('input:checkbox[name=b]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    let val = $(this).data('shape');
    opts.push(val);
    console.log(opts);
  } else {
    let val = $(this).data('shape');
    opts = opts.filter(a => a !== val);
    console.log(opts);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" data-shape="scb4" />


<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" data-shape="mcb4" />
```

array's filter method return a new array, you should assign to 'opts value' that it will work well